# showing Routing Error No route matches error when clicking on link in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I tried to fetch 10 most recent articles's title which is part of blog app using ruby on rails. I did this. But i got stuck when it comes to routing.

When I do like

(this code is part of article/index)

```
<% @article_titles.each do |article_title|%>
              <% if !article_title.nil? %>
               <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px"> <%= link_to article_title.title,
               article_path(article_title) %></div> 
            <% end %>    
            <% end %>
```

It gives me Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>#} error.

I tried another way, like below:-

```
 <% @article_titles.each do |article_title|%>
              <% if !article_title.nil? %>
               <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px"> <%= link_to article_title.title,
               "/articles?id=#{article_title.id}"   %></div> 
            <% end %>    
            <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
match "articles/:id" => "articles#show"
```

I gives no error and only showing `("http://localhost:3000/articles?id=")` in address bar of my browserwith no action taken place.

rake routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                           devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                                                 articles#index
         dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#index
                         POST   /dashboard(.:format)                              dashboard#create
           new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)                          dashboard#new
          edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)                     dashboard#edit
               dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#show
                         PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#update
                         DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)                          dashboard#destroy
                    tags GET    /tags(.:format)                                   tags#index
                         POST   /tags(.:format)                                   tags#create
                 new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                               tags#new
                edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)                          tags#edit
                     tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#show
                         PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#update
                         DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                               tags#destroy
        article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
     new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
    edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
         article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                                /articles/:article_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
                articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                         POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
             new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
            edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
                 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

articles_controller.rb

```
 def index
          @articles = Article.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
      @article_titles = Article.select(:title).first(10)
      end
    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    end
```

routes.rb

```
Mau::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'articles#index'
  resources :dashboard
  resources :tags
  resources :articles do
  resources :comments
  match "articles/:id" => "articles#show"
end
```

debugger logs.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/defaults.js"):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Do i need to add something in show action of article? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the @article_titles records don't contain an id attribute since you're selecting only the title `Article.select(:title)`. A much better way to accomplish what you're trying would be to have in your controller:

```
@articles = Article.order("created_at DESC")
@first_articles = @articles.limit(10)
```

Use @first_articles where you were using @article_titles.

I also question whether you need @articles at all (are you only displaying the first 10 records?) With the code I am suggesting it's an ActiveRecord::Relation and it won't be loaded (hit the database) unless you're actually using the variable in your view, but that's a topic for a different SO question

Comment: You are right. However other solution would be add 'id' in the select

Comment: sure, but the whole thing is awkward; there's hardly any benefit from doing that. Just keep it simple and have every element in the array be an Article instance.

Comment: hi boulder, a big thanks. It worked for me with small change @first_articles = @articles.first(10). When it tried with limit(10), it shows error undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0x4d5c608>. Now it working with first(10). is this right way of doing . any suggestion please. again a big thanks.

Comment: Actually selecting specific fields in SQL can boost performance once Article models tarts to get too big.

Comment: @VSiingh. limit(10) only works if you are defining @articles as I suggested. If you use `Article.all` it hits the database and becomes an array. For performance reasons, I recommend using `Article.order...` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This may or not solve your problem, but you're missing end `end` in your routes block:

```
Mau::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'articles#index'
  resources :dashboard
  resources :tags
  resources :articles do
  resources :comments
  match "articles/:id" => "articles#show"
end
```

should be

```
Mau::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'articles#index'
  resources :dashboard
  resources :tags
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Note that you shouldn't need the `match` route that you have because it's part of the `resources :articles`.

**EDIT**

You should also try passing in only the id like this:

```
<% @article_titles.each do |article_title|%>
    <% if !article_title.nil? %>
         <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px"> 
             <%= link_to article_title.title, article_path(article_title.id) %>
         </div> 
    <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: hi Catfish, I start trying like this only but could not get output. I think , I missing something in show action of article controller because when i do like ur suggestion it gives me Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>#<Article title: "Linkedin">} error, which indicate about "show" action.

Comment: Try my updated answer. Remember to restart your server after making any changes to your routes.

Answer (score 0):

remove `match "articles/:id" => "articles#show"`, make sure `resources :articles` is present, and `article_path(@article)` should work.

Change

```
Article.select(:title).first(10)
```

by

```
Article.select([:id, :title]).first(10)
```

You always needs to select :id to use with routes.

Comment: hi fotanus, I already have resources :articles in routes.rb file and tried with your suggestion but it gives me Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>nil} error.

Comment: can you post a `logger.debug @articles_title` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks. What I was asking is to put the line above in your controller. Then in your server output you should see a line that displays the contents of @articles_title. You could also use debugger and inspect it to get the same result

Comment: Anywhere in your action, you can write stuff like `logger.debug "yey"`. This will print yey in the output of the server, usually the terminal you raw `rails server`. So you can print variables too. What I mean is to put `logger.debug @articles_title.inspect` and check for what appears on your server output. Got it?

Comment: [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) might help

Comment: hi fotanus, i tried with ur suggestion. here is output:- 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>#<Article title: "Linkedin"
  app/views/articles/index.html.erb:46:in `block in _app_views_articles_index_html_erb___775826365_26077764'
  app/views/articles/index.html.erb:43:in `each'
  app/views/articles/index.html.erb:43:in `_app_views_articles_index_html_erb___775826365_26077764'